# How to invoke external scripts/programs from node.js

Tags: python, c++, node.js

I have a `C++` program and a `Python` script that I want to incorporate into my `node.js` web app.

I want to use them to parse the files that are uploaded to my site; it may take a few seconds to process, so I would avoid to block the app as well.

How can I just accept the file then just run the `C++` program and script in a sub-process from a `node.js` controller?

Comment: Is your C++ program being called from within Python or are these two separate calls you will be making? 1) To Python and 2) to C++ app?
Or does Python code load up and call your C++ app?

Comment: Node's `child_process` stuff will run processes async.  If all you want to do is launch a program from within node, that will do it.

Comment: @StevenLeggett The python script and C++ app do not interact at all; I want to call them both separately (they don't need to be in any particular order either).

Comment: if you can execute the c++ app from the command line then my solution should work... you may want to look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to help with control flow e.g. calling python then c++ in series

Answer (score 40, accepted):

see [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). here is an example using `spawn`, which allows you to write to stdin and read from stderr/stdout as data is output. If you have no need to write to stdin and you can handle all output when the process completes, `child_process.exec` offers a slightly shorter syntax to execute a command.

```
// with express 3.x
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
   if(req.files.myUpload){
     var python = require('child_process').spawn(
     'python',
     // second argument is array of parameters, e.g.:
     ["/home/me/pythonScript.py"
     , req.files.myUpload.path
     , req.files.myUpload.type]
     );
     var output = "";
     python.stdout.on('data', function(data){ output += data });
     python.on('close', function(code){ 
       if (code !== 0) {  
           return res.send(500, code); 
       }
       return res.send(200, output);
     });
   } else { res.send(500, 'No file found') }
});

require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

Comment: How are types handled with this format? If I send 0.123 as a parameter, how will python treat it since I think it is coming in as a string?

Comment: @spencer AFAIK URL components, as well as unix/windows shell commands, always use strings for everything so I consider it the python app's responsibility to cast it to a number. how would you tell python it's a number in a normal command line invocation?

Comment: you're right and that makes a lot of sense. I should have thought about it some more haha. Thanks!

Comment: @spencer One thing that might help is to have the node app create a JSON object with your data, that will distinguish number vs. string. Then send it to the python app's stdin and parse it

Answer (score 1):

Might be a old question but some of these references will provide more details and different ways of including python in NodeJS.

There are multiple ways of doing this.

- first way is by doing `npm install python-shell`

and here's the code

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
//you can use error handling to see if there are any errors
PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) { 
//your code
```

you can send a message to python shell using 
`pyshell.send('hello');`

you can find the API reference here-
https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell

- second way - another package you can refer to is node python , you have to do `npm install node-python`
- third way - you can refer to this question where you can find an example of using a child process-
  [How to invoke external scripts/programs from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972788/how-to-invoke-external-scripts-programs-from-node-js)

a few more references -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/python

if you want to use service-oriented architecture -
http://ianhinsdale.com/code/2013/12/08/communicating-between-nodejs-and-python/

Comment: this works if I can spawn a python process from node, I already have a node server running and a python script that runs in daemon thread mode, I want to access a variable in python from node, how would ya do that