# communicate with my raspberry PI, through my webserver

Tags: node.js, webserver, raspberry-pi, communication, robotics

I want to communicate with my raspberry pi, through my webserver. 
I want to use a web interface on my server, with which I can control an LED on my PI. 
Can I use "node js" for this? or does anyone have a good idea or examples?

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use just about any web server to communicate with the pi and thereby control its GPIO pins.

I wrote a web server specifically to interface with the pi's GPIO capabilities complete with utilities and examples if you want to try it out.  It's a very lightweight native-code (C++) web server that you can use to control your LEDs (or what have you) with about 5 mins of setup:

[OliWeb on GitHub](https://github.com/m2ware/OliWeb)

You can install it using git with:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/m2ware/OliWeb.git
```

You could also install just about any other web server out there (Nginx, Node.JS, take your pick) and set up CGIs to call command-line utilities to drive the LED pins.  Gordon's WiringPi utilities are easy to use and install - installation and usage instructions are below.

[Gordon's WiringPi Utility](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/)

Each web server will have its own particulars in terms of invoking command line interfaces via CGI.  If you're interested in NodeJS specifically, this describes how to invoke command-line functionality from Node:

[How to invoke external scripts programs from node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972788/how-to-invoke-external-scripts-programs-from-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little bit late, although for those who may be still interested I've recently developed a school project which does exactly this job.

I've used WebSocket and GPIO handling.

Here's the repo for the client: https://github.com/jkomyno/material-led-controller/

Here's the one for the server (you gotta put this on your RPI):