# Run python code inside <script> tag of HTML file

Tags: javascript, python, html

`(server.js)` I have following code to run my server -

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './public/index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('500 Internal Server error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8000/');
```

`(index.html)` And my index.html file inside public directory is following -

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./algebra.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./math.js"></script> 

    <script>
        //Some more code ...
        function runPythonCode(x, y){
            //process python file and get result
        }
        runPythonCode(2, 3);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In above code inside `runPythonCode` function I want to pass variable `x` and `y` to my python code and do some processing with `x` and `y` and want the value return back to javascript.

I was simply tried like this inside the script tag in index.html just to check if python script is running or not -

```
text = "hello"
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./app.py",
    //data: { param: text}
    success: function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     },
     error: function (error) {
         console.log(error);
     }
  })
```

And my `aap.py` python code -

```
import csv
from numpy import matrix

def main():
    x =2
    return x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x=main()
```

But after running this code I am simply getting whole python code inside console.
What I am doing wrong here? How to run python file inside js?

Comment: Side note: I'd have major security concerns allowing to run arbitrary user code on a server not packed inside a sandbox. You may want to rethink your approach in case you want to put this into production.

Comment: @jbndlr I can modify later for production purpose first I simply want to try this thing whether it is possible to do or not.

Comment: You can't use Python as if it were PHP. You need to have a running Python web server with a callable REST endpoint that will execute your code and return the result via HTTP.

Comment: @GorkaHernandez Ok. Can you please explain it by giving an example.

Comment: I am not too familiar as to create an educated example featuring this behavior, though this link to the Python documentation may be a good start: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html, you basically need to create an HTTP server like you have done with Node.js above.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called brython which allows you to add python 3 code inside a script tag of html file.

However, I assume it works by converting your python code into javascript and have it consumed by the browser. Here is an example of how a python script might look like:

```
<script type="text/python">
"""Code for the clock"""

import time
import math

from browser import document
import browser.timer

sin, cos = math.sin, math.cos
width, height = 250, 250 # canvas dimensions
ray = 100 # clock ray

background = "#111"
digits = "#fff"
border = "#333"

def needle(angle, r1, r2, color="#000000"):
    """Draw a needle at specified angle in specified color.
    r1 and r2 are percentages of clock ray.
    """
    x1 = width / 2 - ray * cos(angle) * r1
    y1 = height / 2 - ray * sin(angle) * r1
    x2 = width / 2 + ray * cos(angle) * r2
    y2 = height / 2 + ray * sin(angle) * r2
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff"
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
    ctx.stroke()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only client-side scripting language that's supported by browsers is JavaScript. Python is not suitable for the web.

If you are interested in using python on server-side: https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: @iBug I tried Flask also that was also giving same full python code in response.

Comment: @S.I. What part of the link needs to be included inside the answer, if I look at the answer, it just seems like nothing is needed from the link itself

Answer (score 0):

Your node.js HTTP server is configured to not execute python scripts; consequently, they are delivered as plain text to the caller.

In your node.js server, you can use the `npm` module for executing python like so: [How to call python script from NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689526/how-to-call-python-script-from-nodejs/30689597)

However, still **be warned!** Never, ever execute code that comes from or may be altered by your site visitors.