# Running python script on cmd(Windows) through java script

Tags: javascript, python, cmd

I have an application where the output is written into a file (.py) by using javascript.

I'm using this application to write python script into the file. Now I want to run the python script automatically on cmd(Windows) right after the output was written.

Is there a way to do so ? Is it possible without using "NodeJS"

So apparently everything happens with a single click on the application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Node js provides the [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module,
which you can use to basically spawn a child process from your js application.

since you have not shared any source code so i am not sure what your specific use case is but a basic way of spawning python script would be like this.

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
let scriptPath = './script.py'    // path to your python script
var script = spawn('python', ['-u', scriptPath, arg1, arg2]);  // arg1,arg2 can be any command line arguments required by your script or if not needed you can skip them.
script.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log('Data: ', data.toString());
    // implement your functionality here
});
```

you can similary bind on close and error events to your script and implement the functionality accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not storing your script in a script.py file? Why do you use .txt at all? With CMD and Python installed you should easily run .py scripts with  a command line "python path/to/script.py", shouldn't you?

Edit: For checking out how to execute python on Node JS just use Google! Google is your friend! "execute python with node js" threw me this article: [How to call python script from NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689526/how-to-call-python-script-from-nodejs)

Comment: Yes, I'm storing it in a .py file but how can I run the file from the javascript coz, I don't want to run it by manually opening cmd and all. I want that to be done automatically whenever the script is being written on .py file. I'm a complete beginner, sorry if I'm asking basic questions.