# python script in a typescript file

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

how do I use my python script in a typescript file? Like how do I link it ? I have to traverse a xml file which I have a python code which updates some details and wanted to use it in the typescript server file.

Like the server should update some details in a xml file. this update functionality is implemented in python and I wanted to use it in the typescript server code.

Comment: Transpile (port) the Python script into TypeScript? Or run it through the shell?

Comment: You can create a new process and call the python code. Look into inter-process communication. This can get messy with passing arguments and getting output back. You may be better of rewriting the Python code in TypeScript.

Comment: See if this is want you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689526/how-to-call-python-script-from-nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the python script in node using `exec()`: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback

A minimal example assuming you have `python3` installed on the machine running your node script could be:

```
// shell.py

print('printed in python')
```

```
// server.js

import {exec} from 'child_process'
//if you don't use module use this line instead:
// const { exec } = require('child_process')

exec('python3 shell.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
  }
  else if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }
  else {
    console.log(stdout);
  }
})
```

```
// using it in the shell

% node server.js

// should output this:

printed in python
```

This way you could traverse your XML file, change it and output it to the js/ts file, or save it as a file and just read that via your js/ts code.